# Asp.net web.config Handle Error page "File or directory not found"

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, web-config

I have page i.e. **Default.aspx**. I can handle error pages like 404,403. But when I change the extention of page then server give me an error.If I change **Default.aspx** to **Default.asasd**. Here I have just changed the extention of page then server gives following error

[image: Error Page]

I added 404 error page in my web.config file. How can I solve this?

**Web.config**

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/DefaultErrorPage.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
        <error statusCode="404"  redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="403"  redirect="~/ErrorPages/403.aspx" />
   </customErrors>
```

Comment: how did you write your custom error pages in your web.config. paste the section.

Comment: Thank you for reply @AMember I added web.config in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```